# How to use js data in a template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn some useful skills while creating my Resume Website, so I decided to try Vue.js. I had no trouble understanding the basic structure of the framework, but I have trouble actually manipulating data in .Vue files. 
What I'm trying to do currently is creating two classes in a  tag:

- Skills
- Categories (list of skills with a name)

```
<script>
    class Category {
        name = "";
        skills = [];
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.skills = [];
        }
    }

    class Skill {
        constructor(name, level) {
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
        }
    }

    let programmation = new Category("Programmation");
    let cpp = new Skill("C++", "Confirmed");
    programmation.skills.push(cpp);
    let categories = [].push(programmation, ...);
```

Then, I create a list of categories with skills in them (I showed only one in the example code for clarity), and try to display those in my template as such:

```html
<template>
    <div class="skills">
        <h1 v-for="cat in categories" v-bind:key="cat.name">{{cat.name}}</h1>
        <container xl="1200"></container>
    </div>
</template>
```

For now, I'm only trying to display the names of my categories.

However, the compiler show me this error:

```
error: 'categories' is assigned a value but never used (no-unused-vars) at src\views\Skills.vue:72:5:
  71 |
> 72 | let categories = [].push(programmation, ...);
     |     ^
  73 |
  74 | export default {
  75 |   name: "skills",
```

while I'm using this value in the template. How am I supposed to define and use Js variables in my template?

Comment: Can you please share the complete component code?

Comment: Of course, but it's a bit long, I will host it on a notepad and edit the question

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using categories as reactive property inside vue component, but you need to register to make it reactivity

Here is the fix in export:

```
export default {
  name: "skills",
  data() {
     return {
       categories: categories,
     };
  },
  components: {
    //Skill
  }
};
```

Here is the sample codepen: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/YzzGOMz?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, it resolved the issue of the compiler error, but it's still displaying nothing on the page. Since it's another problem, I'll mark this one as resolved, thanks a lot!